# How do I get imported KML circles to appear as circles rather than ellipses in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, circle, ellipse

I have a QGIS project, CRS is WGS84 (EPSG 4326).

I have OpenStreetMap as the base layer. I have loaded some point features. I have created a buffer zone around some of these features with WGS84 as the CRS. All good.

I have loaded some KML circles, generated both by functions on an external website and also by my code (as Lat and Lon pairs). These appear as circles when loaded into Google My Maps but as ellipses in QGIS, with the long axis oriented E-W. CRS of these is WGS84.

If I change the CRS of the project to WGS84/Pseudo Mercator (EPSG 3857), which I believe Google uses, the ellipses turn into circles, but the QGIS-generated buffer zones turn into ellipses oriented N-S! If I set the CRS of the buffer zone layer to WGS84/Pseudo Mercator (EPSG 3857) the buffer zones disappear altogether!

When I save the buffer layer (presented as ellipses) to a KML file and import into Google My Maps they appear as ellipses here too.

'On the fly' transformation is enabled.

I'd obviously like both my own generated circles and QGIS-generated buffer zones to all appear as circles but it seems I can have either one of the other.

What am I doing wrong?

Ta for your input!

Comment: Have you done any research in stack exchange. I've come across similar questions: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/199385/73835

Comment: also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/how-to-create-an-accurate-tissot-indicatrix

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. Yup, I have been perusing the question both here and via elsewhere Google. I think I have found the answer [here](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0111/geodesic.html). It all seems down to geodesic or euclidean buffering. Seems that QGIS uses geodesic.